# if variable = 1 then checkbox = checked

Tags: php

I want to say if

```
$supervisor = 1
```

then

```
checkbox=checked else checkbox=unchecked
```

I have used:

```
<input name="supervisor" type="checkbox" <?php if ($supervisor = 1){?> checked="checked" <?php } else { ?> checked="unchecked" <?php } ?>/>
```

and `echo $supervisor;` returns 0

however the box is ticked?

Any Help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Without submitting a form, you can not check if it is checked or not UNLESS you use, Ajax/Jquery

Comment: I am not submitting the form, just displaying a checkbox

Answer (score 6):

Don't specify a `checked` attribute if it's not checked. Also, a single equal is assignment, you want to use two.

```
<input name="supervisor" type="checkbox" <?php if ($supervisor == 1){?> checked="checked" <?php } ?>/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<input name="supervisor" type="checkbox" <?php if ($supervisor == 1) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> />
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this.

```
echo ( $supervisor == 1 ) ? 'checked' : 'not checked';
```

Ternary operators are clear and concise when doing things like that.

Comment: There is no attribute value for "unchecked".

Comment: its called pseudo code, he can perform whatever operations he wants to in there

Comment: It is not ternary syntax, but ternary operator. Because, it behaves, walks and is shiny like an operator

Comment: It's a clear example the person who asked, knows to leave the false condition empty so instead of 'not checked' will put empty quotes''. I don't get it when someone simply down votes an answer instead of enriching the argument.

Answer (score 0):

First problem: **The HTML you are trying to generate will not achieve what you want.**

If you have a `checked` attribute then it must have the value `"checked"`.

If you want to specify that a checkbox should not be checked by default then you *must not* include the `checked` attribute at all. `checked="unchecked"` is an error that browser error recovery will treat as `checked="checked"`.

Second problem: **`=` is an assignment operator, you need a comparison operator.**

Use `==` instead.

**Fixed code**

```
<input
    name="supervisor"
    type="checkbox"
    <?php if ($supervisor == 1) { ?>
    checked="checked"
    <?php } ?> 
    />
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
<input name="supervisor" type="checkbox" <?php if ($supervisor) echo "checked" ?> />
```

Comment: Because it is not complying to XHTML rules.

Comment: in XHTML it must be **<input checked="checked" />**

Answer (score -3):

You can do this with shorthand if:

```
 <input name="supervisor" type="checkbox" <?php echo $supervisor == 1 ? 'checked' : ''  ?>/>
```

Comment: There is no "unchecked" attribute value.

Comment: There is also no allowed value "true" or "false" for the attribute "checked" of an input element. Too bad I cannot downvote twice.